# How to implement single sign on MVC 2 using ADFS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, adfs

I have MVC 2 application which has used in Windows authentication mode. The requirement has changed to that application needed to be on single sign one(SSO) in multiple active directories.The client has developed ADFS in their environment. Unfortunately, I'm new to the ADFS authentication technology. Does anyone can say how to implement this in MVC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way is via [OWIN](http://developers.de/blogs/armin_kalajdzija/archive/2016/10/06/how-to-implement-web-sign-on-with-adfs-in-asp-net-mvc-using-owin.aspx).

If you can't do that with earlier versions of MVC, then look at [WIF](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adfs2-federation-wif-application-step-by-step-guide(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Is OWIN allow in MVC 2? when i tried to install the OWIN using nuget package it didn't allow.

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Try WIF.